# Что считать цельным словосочетанием?

Tags: синтаксис, подлежащее, цельное-выражение

*Двое незнакомых людей село на скамейку.*
Входит ли слово "незнакомых" в цельное словосочетание и нужно ли его тоже подчеркивать одной линией (как подлежащее)?

Answer (score 1):

Подлежащим здесь является цельное сочетание (счетный оборот) "двое людей".
Это сочетание слов со значением количества. Собирательное числительное "двое" — это разновидность количественного числительного "два": двое людей = два человека.
"Незнакомых" (каких?) — это определение.

Я бы написала так:
*Двое незнакомых людей **сели** на скамейку.*

> **5.** При числительных два, три, четыре, двое, трое, четверо сказуемое обычно ставится в форме множественного числа, например: <...> ***Двое рабочих** в белых фартуках **копались** около дома* (Чехов).

Минут десять он смотрел, как **двое людей** с лицами наркоманов **играли** в карамболь. [Сергей Юрский. Чернов (1972-1978)]

**Двое людей** в военной форме **вынесли** из-за кулис на эстраду громоздкую позолоченную лиру на подставке и табурет. [Виктор Пелевин. Чапаев и пустота (1996)]

*Двое незнакомых людей **попытались** помешать съемке* ([из учебника](https://books.google.ee/books?id=LuhNDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT558&lpg=PT558&dq=%22%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9!&source=bl&ots=MtVpvPWgfR&sig=ACfU3U1lea7DFwXbD8gvQqh7io3WOb6YFg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiytIOgxvv5AhUnx4sKHeO0ApI4HhDoAXoECBAQAw#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9!&f=false) Н. Киреевой).

[Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20(%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).)

Comment: И оно так подчёркивается? С пропуском слова? Будто два подлежащих.

Comment: Вроде бы на подлежащее есть только одна линия, если только это не однородные подлежащие. Разве нет?

Comment: Нет. ***Шапка** русых **кудрей** колыхалась на его голове.* Подчеркивается с пропуском определения. Или определений: *Около полудня обыкновенно появляется **множество** круглых высоких **облаков***. (https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/701-12_podlezhaschee.html)

Comment: БЛГАГОДАРЮ ЗА ОТВЕТ, Римма Михайловна)

Comment: И-эх-эх, Олег Лангенберг, Римма Михайлова я!.. Если Вы считаете мой ответ полезным (возможно, и чей-то еще), то можно нажать на треугольник "ответ полезен" (это +10 баллов к репутации отвечающего). Можно и принять его, поставив галочку ("ответ принят"), если он решил Вашу проблему (это тоже дополнительные баллы, что, право слово, хоть немного стимулирует).

Answer (score 0):

В данном случаем полное прилагательное "незнакомых" считается - как определение, к нему можно задать вопрос:

людей (каких?) незнакомых (существительное+прилагательное)

Основа этого предложения:

двое (подлжещаее, выражено числительным) село (сказуемое, выражено глаголом в личной форме)

Comment: По-моему слово "двое" в данном предложении не обозначает предмета речи, поэтому подлежащим является словосочетание "двое людей"